# Python package 'Invalid ELF header'

Tags: python, linux, django, pip

on my production server when I put in the command 'python2.7 manage.py collectstatic' it throws an error about one of the packages that I installed.

```
'/home/humanlink/webapps/backend_2016/human_link/third_party/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/_openssl.so: invalid ELF header'.
```

I was having issues using pip to install the cryptography package on my production server, so instead I used pip install on my development server, and used linux 'mv' to mv that package folder to a third party directory in my application. It works on the development server, and it is the same exact package code for code, so Im not entirely sure why it is throwing this error ?

Comment: The given file is not in the right format. It is not a usable as a library by your system. A good first step would be to run `file <path_to_file>` on that file to see what it actually is.

Comment: /home/humanlink/webapps/backend_2016/human_link/third_party/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/_openssl.so: Mach-O fat file with 2 architectures.

Comment: That seems to be a MacOS file. You need the version matching your OS.